# Gmail account reset but I don't have the same 'phone number to get the reset code

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I'm trying to reset my password to my Google Account.

I do not have the same phone number to get the reset verification code.

What to do now?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called "verify your Identity". Use that, provide accurate information and you will get your account back ! its better if you have your alternate email id (verification email id) in your control.